# what is the reason that 'randomNumber1' is always assigned by '0' though i use Random.Range(0,2)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to randomly assign 0 or 1 to `randomNumber1`, but I failed with this code.

This is the code in Unity

```
public class Practice : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int randomNumber1;   
    public static int randomNumber2;

    public class randd
    {
        public void randdom_dd()
        {
            int randomNumber1 = Random.Range(0, 2);
            if (randomNumber1 == 0)
            {
                int randomNumber2 = 1;
            }

            else
            {
                int randomNumber2 = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    public void OnClick()
    {
        if (randomNumber1 == 0)
        {
            print("정답!");   
        }

        else
        {
            print("틀렸어!");
        }

    }
}
```

I think, when I play the codes, `randomNumber1` has always same int. I've tried to change the min and max in `Random.Range(min, max)` and some tries, I failed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need 2 variables? I think you'd be able to get the same functionality, but less complication, out of just using randomNumber1 and checking the value of it in the if/else statements. The upper bound for Random.Range is exclusive, meaning for Range(0,2) only 0 or 1 will ever be returned, which is what you want.

Comment: You don't seem to be triggering `randdom_dd()` anywhere. Try adding it to the OnClick function before you do the IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks all of you! it works with this codes
and yes, you are right, jmrpink. i don't use randomNumber2 in this code. my mistake!

```
public void OnClick()
{
        int randomNumber1 = Random.Range(0, 2);
        if (randomNumber1 == 0)
        {
            int randomNumber2 = 1;
        }

        else
        {
            int randomNumber2 = 0;
        }
    if (randomNumber1 == 0)
    {
        print("정답!");   
    }
    else
    {
        print("틀렸어!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your random_dd method isn't actually being called anywhere.  Because randomNumber1 is defined as a field, it will automatically instantiate to zero.  This is why you are always seeing your random number show up with the same value.

Try calling the random_dd method before the OnClick method is being hit, or just calling the random_dd method at the top of your OnClick method before you evaluate your random variable, and see if that works.  Here's a link to an example that elaborates on the definitions of fields in C# [Defining a Field in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423437/why-do-i-have-to-assign-a-value-to-an-int-in-c-sharp-when-defaults-to-0).

You also shouldn't be using the 'int' keyword when assigning a value to variables that have already been defined in your program, which in your case are the randomNumber1 and randomNumber2 variables.